# Google Now reminders will not store the hour

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-g, google-now

I can reproduce this issue consistently each time.

Using Google Now to store a reminder (either via voice input or by keyboard) will correctly store the title and the date, but not the hour.

If I use the voice input, it recognizes the hour set properly and even displays it to me. After that, it asks if I want to save the reminder, I say 'yes' and it *seems* to be stored properly.

But when I go check it, it has lost the hour and it is set for the entire day.

Is this a known issue? Is there a fix? Can other reproduce this?

Motorola Moto g 3rd gen, Android version 6.0. If I'm correct, the Google Now version is 5.12.35.21.arm.